# MongoDB Query On Array + Indexing

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection (cats) with documents that look like this. The meals array can have a minimum of 0 and a maximum of 3 elements.

```
{
"catID": 10001,
"catName": "muffler",
"meals" : [
    {
        "mealID": 67890,
        "mealDate" : "03/02/1999",
        "mealCost" : 102,
    },
    {
        "mealID" : 67899,
        "mealDate" : "2/2/2014",
        "mealCost" : 203,
    }
]
```

}

I want to find the top 5 cats that consumed the most amount of money on meals. I have written the following query to return this result:

```
db.cats.aggregate([{$match: {"meals": { $elemMatch: {"$exists": true}}}}, {$unwind: {"path": "$meals"}}, {$group: {"_id": {"catID": "$catID", "catName":"$catName"},"catTotalSpend": {"$sum": "$meals.mealCost"}
}}, {$sort: {"catTotalSpend": -1}}, {$limit: 5}, {$project: {"_id": 0, "catID": "$_id.catID","catName": "$_id.catName", "catTotalSpend": 1}}])
```

Is there a better way to write the same query without using the aggregation framework? If not, what kind of Indexes might I create on this query that might improve performance. Thanks.

Comment: you are saying i want to find the top 5 cats, when in your  query you are finding the top 5 meals not top 5 cats, which one you want to do? for example if 2 cats ate the top 5 meals, with your query you will find only 2 cats.

Answer (score 0):

I am confused if you want this but the answer bellow assumes

- each catID is unique in the collection (each cat has 0-3 meals)
- and you want to find the 5 top cats that the sum of their meals are the maximun
  (its not like your query that finds the top 5 meals)

You query cannot be answered on document level.
For example we can't see 1 document and decide if its the one we need.
=> index to be used on find is not useful

It can be answered on collection level after sort.
=> index can store the sort order => no sorting just use the index.

But here you don't have a field to sort on

I think you should

- add 1 more field called total_meal_cost
- that gets updated when you add meals
- create an index on it

This way your queries will be very fast and simple, 1 sort(that will use the index) and 1 limit.

Answer (score 0):

You should use aggregation since you sort the total meal cost of each cat. It is an accumulator. Since you don't use $match, $group and the sort is preceded by $project the index is not a subject for this pipelines. The query stages should be: sum, sort, limit 5 total meal cost of each cat:

```
    db.cat.aggregate([
        {
            $project: {
                catId: "$catID",
                totalMealCost: { $sum: "$meals.mealCost" },
            }
        },
        { $sort: { totalMealCost: -1 } },
        { $limit: 5 }
    ])


      
//output:
        {
      "_id": "61400dd7088f2108b66c08f0",
      "catId": 10003,
      "totalMealCost": 602
    },
    {
      "_id": "61400dd7088f2108b66c08f2",
      "catId": 10002,
      "totalMealCost": 502
    },
    {
      "_id": "61400dd7088f2108b66c08f1",
      "catId": 10004,
      "totalMealCost": 452
    },
    {
      "_id": "61400dd7088f2108b66c08f3",
      "catId": 10006,
      "totalMealCost": 402
    },
    {
      "_id": "61400dcd088f2108b66c08db",
      "catId": 10001,
      "totalMealCost": 305
    }
```